# How do I search Active Directory to find all enabled users that exist in two different organizational units from the same domain?

Tags: windows, powershell, server, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm not very well versed in scripting, but I'm looking to routinely audit the enabled uses in our Active Directory domain. We have users split into multiple organizational units and I would like to search for all users who are enabled and export that info into a single csv file for review by another department.

I'd like to do this with Powershell, but I'm not married to that method.

Right now, I'm using the following to create two files but am having difficulty refining the info down to just the first and last names, then getting the data from different ou's into one file.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter 'enabled -eq $true' -SearchBase "OU=corporate office,OU=company users,DC=company,DC=com" | export-csv -Path c:\files\corporate_users.csv
```

and

```
Get-ADUser -Filter 'enabled -eq $true' -SearchBase "OU=branch office,OU=company users,DC=company,DC=com" | export-csv -Path c:\files\branch_users.csv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An object can and always does exist in only ONE location in the Active Directory. By that assertion, NO, a user cannot exist in two different OUs in an Active Directory domain at the same time.

So in AD terms, a user account has a single-value attribute in the OU, and a multi-value attribute in groups.

You are doing absolutely right. I am just making it a single script for you which you can utilize as per your requirement. Just create a single ps1 file and execute the below script.

I have added comments also in the script for your reference.

```
# First line is creating the CSV File and capturing only the Four Properties which I have passed in the Select part
Get-ADUser -Filter 'enabled -eq $true' -SearchBase "OU=corporate office,OU=company users,DC=company,DC=com" |Select Name,SamAccountName,DistinguishedName,Surname| export-csv -Path c:\files\corporate_users.csv

# Second line is Appending the data in the same csv file which the 1st line has been created with the same properties.
Get-ADUser -Filter 'enabled -eq $true' -SearchBase "OU=branch office,OU=company users,DC=company,DC=com" |Select Name,SamAccountName,DistinguishedName,Surname| export-csv -Path c:\files\branch_users.csv -Append

# You can segregate them using the DistinguisedName property which will tell that a user is part of which OU.
```

***NOTE:*** You can pick all the properties of the User in the Select as per your requirement.

Feel free to accept the answer if this satisfies you that will help others too.

Comment: Get-aduser TestUser01 -properties * | Get-Member 

will give you all the available properties for that particular user which you can use accordingly.

Comment: Thank you Ranadip, this helped out quite well too.

Answer (score 0):

ok so all you need to do here is store the results from your first command as an array into a variable, then add the results of the second command to that array, after that we can go ahead and filter the results and then export to CSV file.

```
$results = Get-ADUser -Filter 'enabled -eq $true' -SearchBase "OU=corporate office,OU=company users,DC=company,DC=com"
$results += Get-ADUser -Filter 'enabled -eq $true' -SearchBase "OU=branch office,OU=company users,DC=company,DC=com"

$results | select-object GivenName,SurName | export-csv -Path c:\files\branch_users.csv
```

Note that if you are planning to get ALL enabled users anyway you can just eliminate the `-SearchBase` parameter and run the Get-Aduser with only the filter.  you may also want to try running `Get-aduser SOMEUSERNAME -properties * | Get-Member` which will show you the names of the (many) properties available on ADUSER objects.

Comment: Thank you Mike, this worked out great for me. I'm curious though, do you know of documentation to explain the use of += in your solution?

Comment: Sure that's what's called an 'assignment operator' and is used to add new elements to the end of an array, and the same syntax can be used to add data to the end of a string or to increase an integer.  Its basically shorthand for `$results = $results + YOURCODE` for *way* more information check out [This Link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848303.aspx) which is a bit dense but has all the info you could ever want, assignment operators are about half way down the page.